# How can I "render region" for an image sequence from the compositor?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

- Blender 3.5.1
- NVIDIA 3080 RTX
- i7-12700F

[image: compositing nodes]

[image: render settings]

I've got a cropped composite green screen/chroma key that I'm trying to render out to an image sequence. I'm trying to improve the performance of including the image sequence by using a smaller image file (lower resolution, only the pixels with "stuff").

Unfortunately, despite the crop and the checks on "render region," "crop to region," and the viewer region/crop clearly set small, I still get full 1920x1080 images.

How can I get the compositor to render out only the specified region and not the entire resolution?